# What is the advantage of using bash -c over using a here string?

Tags: bash, here-string

Is there any real benefit to using `bash -c 'some command'` over using `bash <<< 'some command'`

They seem to achieve the same effect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44350291/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-bash-c-over-using-a-here-string - [Do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/194222)

Comment: Hi @Patrick thanks for the notice. I really wasn't sure about where the best place to post was. Since, on the one hand this is a Linux question, but on the other hand bash is a kind of scripting language and the other site has more visitors. In a case like this, where would the more appropriate place be to post?

Comment: @yosefrow: Either site would have been fine IMHO; but crossposting is obnoxious (you're asking people on both sites to spend time on your question, without giving them the benefit of each others' answers).

Comment: Would it be appropriate to delete the post from one of the sites then?

Comment: Another minor difference is that `bash -c '...'` will work in shells that do not have herestrings. You are assuming that bash will be called within a bash shell but this will not always be the case.

Comment: The other copy has now been closed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`bash -c 'some command'` retains access to the standard input of the caller, so [`read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read) or commands reading from standard input will work normally. `bash <<< 'some command'` replaces that input with the line being passed in, so `bash -c cat` and `bash <<< cat` do different things.

```
$ bash -c cat
abc
abc
^D
$ bash <<< cat
$
```

On the other hand, you could make use of that feature to provide your own standard input to be used through [`$'...'`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting), if you're very careful:

```
$ bash <<< $'read x y\nabc def ghi\necho $y'
def ghi
$
```

I wouldn't want to rely on that, but it could be convenient sometimes.

---

`bash -c` also allows arguments to be passed to the script, and `$0` to be set:

```
bash -c 'some command' sh abc def
```

will set `$1` to `abc` and `$2` to `def` inside `some command`.

Comment: Syntax errors will also produce slightly different wording. Mainly that the `bash -c` ones mention `-c`, AFAIK. Not entirely pointless, as that can help track them down. `bash <<< 'script'` errors look just like ones in the parent script; `bash -c 'script'` ones do not. You can even label them: `bash -c 'script' label`.

Comment: Well, `bash <<< 'echo $1' /dev/stdin foo` works too, and prints `foo`. Though setting `$0` is somewhat more limited.

Comment: `bash <<< 'echo "$1"' /dev/stdin foo` doesn't always work.  I got `bash <<< 'echo "$1"' -s foo` to work.